# Monitor a process on linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, monitoring, process

I'd like to get an overview of resource usage of one particular process running on a ubuntu server. Can anyone tell me how I'd go about doing that.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

also try htop, you'll have to apt-get install htop , but i like it!
[image]
<sub>(source: [sourceforge.net](http://htop.sourceforge.net/htop-0.5.png))</sub>

Comment: htop is very nice; you can run strace or lsof on a process within htop by highlighting the process and typing 's' or 'l' respectively.

Comment: I didn't know that ,you get +1 for coolness.

Comment: Is there a tool which persist this data periodically and displays graphs to understand the resource usage over time?

Answer (score 3):

You can run [top](http://linux.die.net/man/1/top) and filter on the process or user running the process.